# Updating nested field using JSP and Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Good evening all,

I am trying to update a field in my page and keep getting an exception thrown.

I have a main object "car" that has a foreign key to "Model"

when I built my page I created a select box to list all the models. So now when I choose a model and submit the form I get the exception thrown below. All of the fields that are in the Car table update fine as long as I do not include the model field. Once I try to include the model field, code breaks on submitting.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/sellcar.jsp at line 28

25:                                             <c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
26:                                                     <option
27:                                                             value='<c:out value="${car.model.modId}"/>'
28:                                                             <c:if test="${car.model.model == status.value.model}">SELECTED</c:if>>
29:                                                             <c:out value="${car.model.model}" />
30:                                                     </option>
31:                                             </c:forEach>


**Stacktrace:**
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:111)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1045)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:810)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:723)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:360)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause 
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'model' not found on type java.lang.String
        javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:214)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:191)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:300)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:81)
        javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
        org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
        org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:38)
        org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.sellcar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(sellcar_jsp.java:847)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.sellcar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(sellcar_jsp.java:791)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.sellcar_jsp._jspService(sellcar_jsp.java:107)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:111)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1045)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:810)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:723)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:360)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
</b>
```

My Models:

**Car:**

```
package com.usedcarsearch.domain;

// Generated Feb 19, 2013 10:31:37 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Car generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Car implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer carId;
private Make make;
private State state;
private Model model;
private City city;
private String vin;
private int year;
private String image;
private String engine;
private String trans;
private String mileage;
private BigDecimal price;
private String color;
private BigDecimal hwyMpg;
private BigDecimal cityMpg;
private String address;
private String accessories;
private String comments;
private Set buyers = new HashSet(0);
private Set ownerships = new HashSet(0);
private Set carSearchLists = new HashSet(0);

public Car() {
}

public Car(Make make, State state, Model model, City city, int year,
        String engine, String trans, String mileage) {
    this.make = make;
    this.state = state;
    this.model = model;
    this.city = city;
    this.year = year;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.trans = trans;
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

public Car(Make make, State state, Model model, City city, String vin,
        int year, String image, String engine, String trans,
        String mileage, BigDecimal price, String color, BigDecimal hwyMpg,
        BigDecimal cityMpg, String address, String accessories,
        String comments, Set buyers, Set ownerships, Set carSearchLists) {
    this.make = make;
    this.state = state;
    this.model = model;
    this.city = city;
    this.vin = vin;
    this.year = year;
    this.image = image;
    this.engine = engine;
    this.trans = trans;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.price = price;
    this.color = color;
    this.hwyMpg = hwyMpg;
    this.cityMpg = cityMpg;
    this.address = address;
    this.accessories = accessories;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.buyers = buyers;
    this.ownerships = ownerships;
    this.carSearchLists = carSearchLists;
}

public Integer getCarId() {
    return this.carId;
}

public void setCarId(Integer carId) {
    this.carId = carId;
}

public Make getMake() {
    return this.make;
}

public void setMake(Make make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public State getState() {
    return this.state;
}

public void setState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Model getModel() {
    return this.model;
}

public void setModel(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public City getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(City city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getVin() {
    return this.vin;
}

public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}

public int getYear() {
    return this.year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getImage() {
    return this.image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getEngine() {
    return this.engine;
}

public void setEngine(String engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}

public String getTrans() {
    return this.trans;
}

public void setTrans(String trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
}

public String getMileage() {
    return this.mileage;
}

public void setMileage(String mileage) {
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getColor() {
    return this.color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public BigDecimal getHwyMpg() {
    return this.hwyMpg;
}

public void setHwyMpg(BigDecimal hwyMpg) {
    this.hwyMpg = hwyMpg;
}

public BigDecimal getCityMpg() {
    return this.cityMpg;
}

public void setCityMpg(BigDecimal cityMpg) {
    this.cityMpg = cityMpg;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAccessories() {
    return this.accessories;
}

public void setAccessories(String accessories) {
    this.accessories = accessories;
}

public String getComments() {
    return this.comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public Set getBuyers() {
    return this.buyers;
}

public void setBuyers(Set buyers) {
    this.buyers = buyers;
}

public Set getOwnerships() {
    return this.ownerships;
}

public void setOwnerships(Set ownerships) {
    this.ownerships = ownerships;
}

public Set getCarSearchLists() {
    return this.carSearchLists;
}

public void setCarSearchLists(Set carSearchLists) {
    this.carSearchLists = carSearchLists;
}

}
```

**Model:**

```
        package com.usedcarsearch.domain;

        // Generated Feb 19, 2013 10:31:37 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.Set;

        /**
         * Model generated by hbm2java
         */
        public class Model implements java.io.Serializable {

            private Integer modId;
            private String model;
            private Set cars = new HashSet(0);

            public Model() {
            }

            public Model(String model) {
                this.model = model;
            }

            public Model(String model, Set cars) {
                this.model = model;
                this.cars = cars;
            }

            public Integer getModId() {
                return this.modId;
            }

            public void setModId(Integer modId) {
                this.modId = modId;
            }

            public String getModel() {
                return this.model;
            }

            public void setModel(String model) {
                this.model = model;
            }

            public Set getCars() {
                return this.cars;
            }

            public void setCars(Set cars) {
                this.cars = cars;
            }

        }
```

**Car.hbm**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/
             Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net
             /hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated Feb 19, 2013 10:31:37 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
    <hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
     <class name="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Car" table="Car">
      <id name="carId" type="java.lang.Integer">
       <column name="carId"/>
       <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Make" 
              fetch="select" name="make">
       <column name="fkMakeId" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-one>
      <many-to-one class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.State" 
               fetch="select" name="state">
       <column name="fkStateId" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-one>
      <many-to-one class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Model" 
               fetch="select" name="model">
       <column name="fkModelId" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-one>
              <many-to-one class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.City" 
               fetch="select" name="city">
       <column name="fkZipCode" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-one>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="vin" type="string">
       <column length="25" name="vin"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="year" type="int">
       <column name="year" not-null="true"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="image" type="string">
       <column length="100" name="image"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="engine" type="string">
       <column length="45" name="engine" not-null="true"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="trans" type="string">
       <column length="45" name="trans" not-null="true"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="mileage" type="string">
       <column length="20" name="mileage" not-null="true"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="price" type="big_decimal">
       <column name="price" precision="11"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="color" type="string">
       <column length="20" name="color"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="hwyMpg" type="big_decimal">
       <column name="hwyMpg" precision="3" scale="1"/>
      </property>
     <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="cityMpg" type="big_decimal">
       <column name="cityMpg" precision="3" scale="1"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="address" type="string">
       <column length="50" name="address"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="accessories" type="string">
       <column length="100" name="accessories"/>
      </property>
      <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="comments" type="string">
       <column length="100" name="comments"/>
      </property>
      <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="buyers"
       sort="unsorted" table="Buyer">
       <key>
        <column name="fkCarId" not-null="true"/>
       </key>
       <one-to-many class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Buyer"/>
      </set>
      <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="ownerships"
       sort="unsorted" table="Ownership">
       <key>
        <column name="fkCarId" not-null="true"/>
       </key>
       <one-to-many class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Ownership"/>
      </set>
      <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="carSearchLists"
       sort="unsorted" table="Car_Search_List">
       <key>
        <column name="fkCarId" not-null="true"/>
       </key>
       <one-to-many class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.CarSearchList"/>
      </set>
     </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

**JSP code: (I did not include all but only what is necessary)**

```
 <spring:bind path="command.model">
 <select name='<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>'>
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
    <option value='<c:out value="${car.model.modId}"/>'
    <c:if test="${car.model.model == status.value.model}">SELECTED</c:if>>
    <c:out value="${car.model.model}" />
    </option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed. It seems I had to add the foreign key property in the Car.hbm along with adding the foreign keys variables, getters and setters to Car.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you might want to change line 28 from:

```
status.value.model
```

to

```
status.value
```